# How do I individually load a bullet into a gun?

Tags: dayz-standalone

If I don't have a magazine/clip to a gun in DayZ, how do I load a single bullet into the chamber if I have the proper ammo for it?

Say I have a 9mm handgun and 9mm bullets, how would I put a 9mm bullet into the chamber of the 9mm handgun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion among various forums about this, but [one forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221100/discussions/0/648814841439951083/) that I found states:

> You can chamber 1 Round into the gun without a Magazine otherwise for more than 1 bullet you need a mag
>
> Also In order to put a bullet into a gun it has to be out of the box like the 7.62 you find in boxes empty them and it will turn into a stack of 20 said bullets then you can chamber em

If the ammo is in a box, try emptying them out first, then try dragging the ammo up into the weapon in your inventory to chamber it.

[This video](https://youtu.be/oqhY1KHsoa8?t=7s) demonstrates with the Mosin how you can load just a single bullet. Open your inventory, select the ammo, and drag it up to your weapon.  A drop down should appear that allows you to either "Load Ammo" or "Chamber [weapon name]".  Selecting the "Chamber" option will load a single bullet.

Other sources I've found make it seem like you have to have a magazine for some weapons in order to load ammo into it at all.  In the case of a Mosin, there is no need for a magazine, allowing you to chamber it.  You can try doing this for you pistol, but if it does not work, then I assume it needs a magazine to even be used.

Comment: I've yet to find a gun in DayZ SA that doesn't allow you to chamber one round at a time without a magazine. Granted I've not found all the guns, but in the semi-rare occasion where I actually find a matching weapon and ammo, I'm always able to chamber one round if it requires a magazine I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Tab out and drag the ammunition from your inventory onto the gun - the ammo should highlight orange to signify that it is compatible, it will chamber the round on mouse up.

Or

Hotbar the weapon and the ammo round/stack, whilst the weapon is in your hand hold the key for the hot-barred ammunition, it will chamber it the round. - This is the preferred method for when you are in a PVP situation without a mag as you will not need to tab out.